# Inconsistent font sizes in ticks on Y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I use Seaborn to plot violins, though I assume the bug comes from Matplotlib. I do not do anything fancy regarding the visualization itself, and merely set the font size of tick labels on the Y axis using both

```
sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=1, rc={"lines.linewidth": 1.5})
```

(to adjust globally) and

```
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=19) 
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(19)
```

However, the result I obtain depends on the **value** of the tick's label:

[image: Bad font size]

That is, each time the label is a perfect inverse power of 10 (here 1E-4) I get one font size, and otherwise I get another font size. I tried multiple combinations of values (e.g., changing the "font_scale", or labelsize..), but I never get something consistant. When I set different notation styles:

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=False))

it only affects values that are perfect inverse powers of 10.

The other (maybe) relevant plotting functions I use here are:

```
b = sns.violinplot(data=mydata_without_outliers, cut=0,  palette=colors, scale='width')
ax.set(yscale="log")
sns.scatterplot(data=outlier_data, marker='D', facecolor='blue', edgecolor=(0,0,0), color='blue')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.947, bottom=0.074, left=0.052, right=0.99, hspace=0.095, wspace=0.185);
sns.despine()
```

which produce violin plots with scatterplots superimposed to show outliers.

**EDIT**: To clarify, this is **not** a question about "how to change fonts in Matplotlib" : I could have googled that. This is **not** a question about "how to change minor and major ticks" because this assumes one *already* knows what minor and major ticks are. This question is really about what it is asked above : how to make fonts consistent between powers and non powers of 10, which other questions do not answer, and which the proposed answer by tmdvision perfectly answers. Googling "power of 10 font matplotlib" result in totally different answers to totally different questions, including on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ax.tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html) has a parameter called `which`, which controls whether it will modify the `major` ticks, the `minor` ticks, or `both`.

The default is `major`, and this is what you see -- the major ticks are the integer powers of 10. The minor ticks are everything else.

So the solution is to add `which='both'`:

```py
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelsize=19)
```

If you also want to change the format of the minor ticks, you could add a line like:

```py
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True, useOffset=False))
```